# Using NuGet when developing several dependent projects locally

Tags: nuget

The problem I want to solve is how to work with NuGet on several local projects  that depend on each other without having to copy files around manually and have all sorts of dll issues as a result.

Today my projects (c#) are not using NuGet (working to move them to NuGet), and the way it works is that when working locally all projects build outputs to a "shared bin folder" and all reference from there, so that you alway see the right binaries you are building locally.
On the build server, through some games in the csproj files, projects reference a non-shared bin and get the dependencies there.

How can I achieve the same effect with NuGet? What is the right way to work locally without having to copy dll around manually? (And of course keep the ability to build in the server by getting everything using NuGet normally)
Is there a way to get packages to one bin folder with NuGet or at least folders without version numbers so I can just build and reference from there? And is this even wise?

Assume the latest NuGet, VS versions as required.

Thanks a lot for your help,
Roy.

Comment: I usually just add them all to a single solution and just build everything together. But it would be nice to have a more civilized way to do it using NuGet or something, so this is a good question.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov, thanks :) I was thinking to use a local repo, and maybe update the packages file to point to it when working locally. But that will take everything local which also isn't good since I don't want to have to build everything all the time. Basically I want the Nuget and the local build to output to the same place, but since Nuget packages folders have the version (which is good) it's not constant... Maybe I can infer it somehow. And copy files to that location on a post build step or something...

Comment: Ok, so how about this: in the local build only (somehow...), I will in the post build step get the latest version the the project being build (surely  I can with Nuget) and copy the output dll to that location (I'm already getting all packages to the "shared" location) do you think it's a reasonable plan?

Comment: I have little experience with NuGet, so I can't answer any of that questions, unfortunately. I'm usually a Java programmer, and when I do any .Net development, I just use NuGet to install packages, nothing more.